# Comparing Data Inside CSV Files

Tags: python, csv

I am brand new to Python, so go easy on me!

I am simply trying to compare the values in two lists and get an output for them in `yes` or `no` form.

Image of the `CSV` file storing values in:

[image]

My code looks like this:

```py
import csv

f = open("datatest.csv")
reader = csv.reader(f)

dataListed = [row for row in reader]

rc = csv.writer(f)  

column1 = []
for row in dataListed:
    column1.append(row[0])
    
column2 = []
for row in dataListed:
    column2.append(row[1])

for row in dataListed:
    if (column1) > (column2):
        print ("yes,")
    else:
        print("no,")
```

Currently, the output is just `no, no, no, no, no ...`, when it should not look like that based on the values!

I will show below what I have attempted, any help would be huge.

Comment: What is the point of `rc = csv.writer(f)`?  You never use the `rc` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in dataListed:
    if (column1) > (column2):
        print ("yes,")
    else:
        print("no,")
```

This loop is comparing the same `column1` and `column2` variables each time through the loop.  Those variables never change.

The code does not magically know that `column1` and `column2` actually mean "the first column in the current row" and "the second column in the current row".

Presumably you meant something like this instead:

```
if row[0] > row[1]:
```

... because this actually does use the current value of `row` for each loop iteration.

Comment: I'm assuming OP is looking for integers comparison, so, to produce the expected result, you need to cast `row[0]` and `row[1]` with `int()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code and obtain the expected result with something like this:

```py
import csv
from pathlib import Path

dataset = Path('dataset.csv')

with dataset.open() as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headers = next(reader)

    for col1, col2 in reader:
        print(col1, col2, 'yes' if int(col1) > int(col2) else 'no', sep=',')
```

For the sample `CSV` you posted in the image, the output would be the following:

```
1,5,no
7,12,no
11,6,yes
89,100,no
99,87,yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can get a simple alternative for your program.

```py
f=open("sample.csv")

for each in f:
    header=""
    row=each.split(",")
    try:
        column1=int(row[0])
        column2=int(row[1])
        if column1>column2:
            print(f"{column1}\t{column2}\tYes")
        else:
            print(f"{column1}\t{column2}\tNo")
    except:
        header=each.split(",")
        head=f"{header[0]}\t{header[1].strip()}\tresult"
        print(head)
        print((len(head)+5)*"-")
        pass
```

[image]